# What are some good stealth rules for D&D 3/Pathfinder

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, stealth

So I'm going to run a lone wolf pathfinder campaign with a friend soon, and they want to play a half-orc rogue. I think they're aiming to play kind of a stealthy game, but the pathfinder stealth rules are very heavily flawed for that kind of game. They work in a standard hack'n'slash since they're only rarely used, but they can't be relied upon for a game where a lot of the action will center around sneaking around.

So, do you have any suggestions for stealth rules that could be used with Pathfinder? Whether they're house rules, or using stealth rules from another game, or somewhere in between.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably state up front what you don't like about the PF rules.  (Specifics, I mean.)

Comment: I've put this question on hold as we don't have any criteria to differentiate "good" stealth rules from "bad". After you edit it, I'm happy to reopen.